# How can I split a JFrame in half so that I can have 2 JPanels, 1 that is a map editor and the other that is a tile selector for the map?

Tags: java

I can't seem to get the grid displayed on the first panel for some reason. If anyone knows why I would love to hear that. Also I would like the 1st panel(on the left) to be wider than the panel on the left. I know I can't do that without gridLayout, but I can't seem to find another way. Right now I would like to be able to choose a tile from the panel on the right. I would then have a little window that contains the tile I just picked and I would then just left click to add the tile to the map or right click to remove it. If anyone has any idea how I can do this please help me out. I've gotten started, but I can't seem to get the darn thing to even display the map.

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Grid extends JFrame {

    JFrame window = new JFrame("Map Editor");
    JPanel main = new JPanel();
    JPanel tilePicker = new JPanel();
    JPanel gridHolder = new JPanel();
    JPanel grid = new JPanel();

    public void createGrid() {
        ImageIcon dirt = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Andreas.ANDREAS/Desktop/dirt.png");

        grid.setLayout(new GridLayout(11,11));
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < 11; n++) {
                grid.add(new JLabel(dirt));
            }
        }
    }

    public Grid() {
    //  window = this;

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setBounds(100,100,500,500);
        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        window.setVisible(true);

        gridHolder.add(grid);
        tilePicker.add(new JLabel("TEST"));
        tilePicker.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        main.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        main.add(gridHolder);
        main.add(tilePicker);

        window.add(main);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new Grid();

    }
}
```

When I first made this I wanted to see if the grid would at least display in the JFrame window and it did without any problem. It filled the entire window. Here's the code for that part.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class test extends JPanel {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    ImageIcon dirt = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Andreas.ANDREAS/Desktop/dirt.png");
    ImageIcon blackDefault = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Andreas.ANDREAS/Desktop/black.png");

    JLabel grid = new JLabel();
    grid.setLayout(new GridLayout(11,11));
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        for (int n = 0; n < 11; n++) {
            grid.add(new JLabel(dirt));
        }
    }

    //creates the main JFrame/window
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Map Editor");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setBounds(100,100,500,500);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.add(grid);
    grid.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSplitPane.
One instance has one splitter (2 frames).
If You want to have more splitters - just add a new instance to another.

Add JSplitPane spl to frame.
Add Your components to spl.
Set  bounds, splitter size, defaultPosition, whatever 
run file
EDIT:

```
 Grid(){
  main.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
}
createGrid(){
//Your loops
grid.setBounds(0,0,200,200);
}
```

Itworks for me (i se my icons on a left);

Comment: JSplitPane spl = new JSplitPane();
window.add(spl);
spl.add(grid, tilePicker);                                Would I do something like that? I know that doesn't work but I'm not sure how I could add the grid to the splitpane and how I can add tilePicker to the other side. I also want like a scroll on the right side of the pane and I want the middle bar to be closer to the right pane... I ran it and it acted like each side was a button